# Integrating visual parameters into image file in order to export image

Tags: google-earth-engine, export

When I display the new image layer within the engine, it works like a charm. When I try to export the image file, however, it looses all of its properties that we are interested in for a simple CNN.

How can I include the properties of the visual parameters into the image file or into the export function (as there are no specific argument for them)?

The code:

```
//Landsat data 
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([-81.96, 32.64, -82.39, 32.94]);

var start = ee.Date('2014-01-01');
var finish = ee.Date('2014-02-28');

// I just use the dataset to get an overview over the available images for the given area. 
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
                  .filterDate(start, finish)
                  .filterBounds(geometry);

var visParams = {
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
  min: 0,
  max: 3000,
  gamma: 1.4,
};

var image1 = ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR/LC08_017037_20140217');
//var image1 = ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR/LC08_017037_20140217')
//.visualize(bands(['B4', 'B3', 'B2']),  min(0),  max(3000), gamma(1.4));
//I have tried the two lines above but don't get it properly working. Any 
//recommendations?

image1 = image1.toInt16();

Map.setCenter(-83.1406, 33.2426);


Map.addLayer(image1, visParams);

//What is the best way to carry the above specified information to the Export.image.toDrive() function?


//Export the image, specifying scale and region.
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: image1,
  description: 'Farms_Area_20140217',
  scale: 30,
  region: geometry
});
```

As this is just a short time project and as I have never programmed with JavaScript before, I am just looking for a fast and short answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `image.visualize()` function to create a variable with your visualization parameters. Either assign the visualization parameters using your pre-defined parameters (starting on line 12), or insert them into the code you couldn't quite get working on lines 20 and 21 using the same format as the `var visParams...` line. Below, `image2` and `imageRGB` should be the same thing, since the visualization parameters are identical.

```
var image2 = ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR/LC08_017037_20140217')
    .visualize({bands:['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],  min:0,  max:3000, gamma:1.4});
// Apply visualization parameters to the image
var imageRGB = image1.visualize(visParams);
// Export the image with visualization parameters.
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: imageRGB,
  description: 'MyOutput',
  scale: 30,
  region: geometry
});
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot! 
Indeed, I did not set the {} correctly. Works nicely now.